# Export FBX with nested Empties to Unity correctly?

Tags: export, workflow, unity, parent, .fbx

Okay, so basically I got a huge industrial machine with complex and deep hierarchy in blender. The Empties within my hierarchy will later be animated with Timeline in Unity.
I tried different things for exporting and importing but nothing really helped me. Most Forum Posts I read about don't adress Objects with a lot of nested Children.
The following Lines try to describe some of my attempts of solving the problem but none of this actually did.

[image: Tried to export in various different cases]

There is a Ticket where it's stated, that it is a known limitation for the Experimental Apply Transform Option https://developer.blender.org/T50405

I also tried the Rotation Fix for Unity (basically the 90° "Hack" you could do manually as well) https://forum.unity.com/threads/blender-unity-rotation-fix.181870/

I work with blender for quite a time now but never really had the need of such complex hierarchies. Any Suggestions?
Maybe the only option is to export dozens of single components to prevent a deep hierarchy and compose the whole machine in unity out of several FBX files?
So am I missing something big or is there really no viable workflow after all these years of unity and blender to bring a complex object to unity in one piece without messing up rotations?

Here are the .fbx files with the different Cases https://we.tl/t-GtoZXBIIAO

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am making a game in Unity and know exporting is frustrating. I have been exporting for months and still wonder what went wrong sometimes. In my experience (please correct me if you have a different experience) Empties in Blender don't translate to Unity. I know that sound ridiculous but that was the takeaway I got at some point so I don't use them in hierarchies anymore. Some advice: 1) Before you export anything, Apply Rotation/Scale for all components and move the collection's registration point ("origin") to the scene's origin (0,0,0). 2) Always use the "Experimental Apply Transform".

Comment: ...if you don't, you will find out too late that your imported object won't respond correctly to transform commands in Unity (a rotation axis might be locked, for example). 3) I also suggest that in the FBX exporter, in the Main tab, you click the dropdown that has the option "Use Blender Units" (or whatever) because then you don't have to do tricky stuff with the meta file to scale your imports correctly.

Finally, to host Blender files, I recommend you use BlendExchange because that will allow us to download directly from your question.

Comment: Please attach your .blend file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the tip with the .blends! Empties do somehow translate to Unity https://we.tl/t-mAKWR2hL3C And you're right, applying rotation and scale is important ohterwise there will happen even stranger things :D Usually I don't have problems with the scale when I uncheck the box beside the Scale Slider in the FBX options

Comment: Why wasn't it an option to parent cubes to other cubes? The empties and bones seem superfluous...?

Comment: we prefer not to animate an object with mesh information to keep things clean but I also tried this.. doesn't make any difference sadly :(